# Запись нескольких переменных print в файл

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть вывод скрипта в таком виде, все переменные типа str (там ещё надо разбираться с кодировкой, но это другой вопрос). Как мне записать такую конструкцию в файл? Пятый день пытаюсь найти примеры, прочитал различные материалы но так ничего не получилось, максимум могу записать просто одну переменную в файл, пример ниже.

```
print('Слово:', title_html, '\n')
print('Британская транскрипция:', transcription_html, '\n')
print('Значения слова:', description_html, '\n')
print('Фразовые глаголы:\n', phrase_verbs, '\n')
print('Однокоренные слова:\n', my_cognate_words, '\n')
print('Словосочетания:\n', phrase_html, '\n')
print('Примеры с переводом:\n', phrase_examles, '\n')

# ищем тег p с классом text
phrase_examles_en = soup.findAll("p", {'class': 'text'})
for element in phrase_examles_en:
    print(element.get_text())
```

Код для записи одной переменной у меня такой

```
file = open(str(name_url) + ".txt", "w")
file.write(title_html)
file.close()
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1243414/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b2-txt-python/1243425#1243425

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Соберите в список переменные и запишите его циклом.

```
l = [title_html, transcription_html, description_html] # и тд

with open("file.txt", "w") as f:
    for i in l:
        f.write(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

если со скриптом ничего делать не хочется, то перенаправить вывод в файл

```
$ python main.py > out.log
```

а можно перенаправить вывод принтов в файл

```
output = open("print", "a+")
a = "There"
print("Hello", a, file=output)
output.close()
```